# Can we use EnumDataType attribute with string property to validate enum values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am validating string property corresponding valid enum values. EnumDataType attribute is not workign. Can I use EnumDataType attribute to validate string property? Or Do I need to write a custom validator for this?

Here is my code

```
[Required]
[EnumDataType(typeof(SubscriptionsActionType), ErrorMessage = "SubscriptionsAction is not valid")]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SubscriptionsAction")]
public string SubscriptionsAction { get; set; }
```

Comment: i think you could create a custom validator and use ``Enum.IsDefined`` to check validity.

Comment: I'll post string values. Will Enum.IsDefined work in that case?

Comment: yeah, its work like : ``Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SubscriptionsAction), "MemberOfEnumLikeAString")``